# multi-line x tick labels using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot with 2 xtick labels for the x-axis.

My code is given below.  It does not create the x-ticks as I expected (In fact there is no xticks label in my pdf).  I followed the code snippet given in the link 
https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiline.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc

filename = 'small-dg-ss.pdf'
rc('mathtext', default='regular')
rc('lines',lw=2.6)
rc('lines',mew=2.4)
rc('text', usetex=True)

x = np.array([5,10,20,50])

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
disp_dcg = np.array([0.85, 0.88, 0.93, 1.0])

ax1.plot(x,disp_dcg,'bs:')
ax1.set_ylabel('GD',color='b',size=14)
ax1.set_ylim([0.7,1.02])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
disp_gc = np.array([1.0, 0.98, 0.95, 0.92])

ax2.plot(x,disp_gc,'rv:')
ax2.set_ylabel('LS',color='r',size=14)
ax2.set_ylim([0.7,1.02])

plt.xticks([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8], [r"$\beta = 0.1$ 
 $\alpha = 0.99$", r"$\beta = 0.5$ 
 $\alpha = 0.89$", r"$\beta = 0.8$ 
 $\alpha = 0.51$", r"$\beta = 0.9$ 
 $\alpha = 0.33"] )
fig.savefig(filename,format='pdf',transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
```

I do not want the entries in the variable x to appear in x-axis, but the ticks I explicitly specify.

Comment: What's wrong with the output you get?

Comment: it does not have the xticks i specify with the  plt.xticks function. there is no xticks in my output

Comment: You have a linebreak within the string literal. Best start by putting that all in a single line, once that works, add newlines where allowed (e.g. at commas).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I am following this article.  https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiline.html

Comment: Yes, look at the difference. In that example all strings are in the same line.

Comment: Also, the example does not use latex.